# zone transfer denied

Tags: dns, bind

I spent many hours to fix my problem but I did not get it done what I needed to fix this issue.I assume may be some problem with file permission.I changed I wanted to verify  the zone transfer from master server using this command:

```
dig ns.insec -t axfr
```

Here is an error message from the master server

```
Mar 16 03:49:30 ip-172-31-22-11 named[5395]: client        127.0.0.1#37251    
    (ns.insec): zone transfer 'ns.insec/AXFR/IN' denied
```

Here is the `named.conf.options` file:

```
acl "trusted" {
    localhost;
    172.31.0.0/20;
    localnets;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

     forwarders {
        8.8.8.8;
     };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    forward only;
    allow-query-cache { trusted; };
    allow-query { trusted; };
    allow-recursion { trusted; };
    recursion yes;
    allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; 127.0.0.1; };
    //also-notify { trusted; };
};
```

Here is my `named.conf.local` file:

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "ns.insec" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.ns.insec";
    allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; };
    also-notify { 172.31.31.48; };
};

// 172.31.31.48 is the IP for slave 
// 172.31.22.11 is the IP for the master
zone "22.31.172.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.172.31.22";
    allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; };
    also-notify { 172.31.31.48; };

};
```

Here is a snapshot of the file permission from master server and is also same for slave server:

[image]

**N:B I can `dig ns.insec -t axfr` from the slave and it works but not from master server**

Comment: The zonal `allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; };` has overwritten the global `allow-transfer` declaration..use `allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; 127.0.0.1; };` in `zone "ns.insec"` definition too..

Comment: +1 for this quick answer.I am gonna upvote you deserve it @heemayl

Comment: Glad i could help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global declaration of any option (in `options`) can be overwritten by a local declaration (e.g. in `zone`, `view`) of the same option.

The same is happening in your case too.

You have a global option `allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; 127.0.0.1; };` which is overwritten by the declaration in the zone definition `zone "ns.insec"` as `allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; };`. So you won't be able to transfer the zone to localhost.

To solve this, make the declaration in `zone "ns.insec"` as

```
allow-transfer { 172.31.31.48; 127.0.0.1; };
```

Or if you want to use the global one (which is not a good idea always), remove the `allow-transfer` directive from `zone "ns.insec"` definition.

Comment: I am implementing this in my home network so If I swap the role from master to slave[ this machine should work [ as primary server  for **ns.insec**and slave server for **not.insec**] in one machine and in the other machine slave to master[primary server for **not.insec** and slave server for **ns.insec**]. Here comes the same problem zone transfer permission denied.But according to your advice I configured that but it works one way from machine 1 but but machine 2 can not transfer the zone file.Could someone advice me to fix this issue.

Comment: @bhordupur zone can be transferred from master to slave..did you change the declarations that which one is zone master and which one is slave? Also you can push update to master to implement DDNS, check `allow_update` directive..

Comment: Yes , I swap the configuration file and they are declared properly. But now i can **dig ns.insec -t axfr ** and **dig not.insec -t axfr ** from the machine 1 and it is transfering the zone file but machine two can dig but can not transfer the zone file.Ok I add **allow-update** now

Comment: @bhordupur Hard to say without looking the configurations..perhaps you should ask a new question with details..

Comment: Alright.I am gonna put a question in few minutes.I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: I put a new question regarding this issue [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/746749/zone-transfer-file-is-denied)

Comment: `allow-update`  don't fix the issue.

Comment: @bhordupur I'm not at my desk right now..will have a look when I get a chance.. Hopefully someone else might have a look in the meantime :)

Comment: Alright.I appreciate your effort